# How to set the tempo of the music extracted from a midi file using Java Sound API?

Tags: java, audio, midi, javasound

I am able to extract the tempo from the midi file using `.getTempoInBPM()` but somehow the function `.setTempoFactor()` that I'm using does'nt seem to alter the tempo of the music the soft synth is generating. I know the problem definitely lies with the function `Thread.sleep()` I'm using after the `.noteOn(key,velocity)` function in every iteration of a midi message.
But I cannot find a possible alternative to it.

I'm attaching my code along.
Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    import java.io.*; 
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.sound.midi.*;

    public class Test1 {

    public static final int NOTE_ON = 0x90;
    public static final int NOTE_OFF = 0x80;

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

int instrmt = 0;
    int tempo = 120;
    String filename = null;
    Sequencer sequencer;
sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer(); 

    Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(new File("STE-003-chord.mid")); 
    sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
    int a = 0; 

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
float fBPM;
System.out.println("Enter tempo");
fBPM=input.nextFloat();

    float tempoBPM = sequencer.getTempoInBPM();
    System.out.println(tempoBPM);
    float fFactor= fBPM / tempoBPM;
     sequencer.setTempoFactor((float)(fFactor));

    String inst[] = new String[131];
     try
    {
        Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synth.open();
        MidiChannel channels[] = synth.getChannels();
        Soundbank bank = synth.getDefaultSoundbank();
        synth.loadAllInstruments(bank);
        Instrument instrs[] = synth.getLoadedInstruments();
    for (int i=0; i < instrs.length; i++)
    {
            System.out.println((i+1)+". "+instrs     [i].getName());
            inst[i+1] = instrs[i].getName();
    }
         String str;
        Instrument instrument = null;
        System.out.println("Enter an instrument number.");
        int s = input.nextInt();
        str=inst[s];
        for (int i=0; i < instrs.length; i++)
        {
            if (instrs[i].getName().equals(str))
            {
                instrument = instrs[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (instrument == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Instrument not compatible.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Patch instrumentPatch = instrument.getPatch();
        channels[0].programChange(instrumentPatch.getBank(),
            instrumentPatch.getProgram());
    int trackNumber = 0;
    for (Track track :  sequence.getTracks()) {
        trackNumber++;
        System.out.println();
        for (int i=0; i < track.size(); i++) { 
            MidiEvent event = track.get(i);
            //System.out.print("@" + event.getTick() + " ");
            MidiMessage message = event.getMessage();
            if (message instanceof ShortMessage) {
                ShortMessage sm = (ShortMessage) message;

                if (sm.getCommand() == NOTE_ON) {
                    int key = sm.getData1();
                    int octave = (key / 12)-1;
                    int note = key % 12;
                   // String noteName = NOTE_NAMES[note];
                    int velocity = sm.getData2();

                   channels[0].noteOn(key,velocity);
                Thread.sleep(1000); //This might create the problem
                } else if (sm.getCommand() == NOTE_OFF) {
                    int key = sm.getData1();
                    int octave = (key / 12)-1;
                    int note = key % 12;
                   // String noteName = NOTE_NAMES[note];
                    int velocity = sm.getData2();

                   channels[0].noteOff(key);
                }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
   }
```

Comment: `setTempoFactor()` affects the sequencer, which you are not using.

Comment: I didn't quite get what you said. Did you mean I'm setting the tempo factor for the sequencer but using the sequence to extract the Tracks?? If yes, could you let me know what could be done alternatively??

Comment: Use the sequencer to play everything. Or use the events' timestamp to do your timing.